# Output blank from python hadoop mapper

Tags: python, hadoop, mapper

Input text is as such, repeated a kabillion times:

```
value1 | foo="bar" value2 | value3
```

I wrote a basic mapper in python for a basic streaming job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.replace('foo=','')
    line = line.replace('"','') # kills double-quotes
    print line
    # alternatively, I have tried print >>sys.stdout, line
```

I run the job as such; it runs without error but output file is empty:

```
bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar -file ~/mapper1.py -mapper mapper1.py -input hdfs:///rawdata/0208head.txt -output hdfs:///rawdata/clean0208.txt
```

I assumed that without a mapper, the print would just print to the output file.   I'm suspecting now that the print command is just printing the output to memory of each JavaVM and without some explicit way to write it back, it just dies in the VM.

I wrote a basic reducer that just took sys.stdin and printed to sys.stdout as above in "#alternatively".  That didn't work either.

Guidance most welcome.  Thanks

Comment: If you are satisfied with answer then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed below steps to execute the hadoop streaming job :

1) First I have created text file called `head.txt` which contains line mentioned by you.

```
value1 | foo="bar" value2 | value3
```

2) Then I saved this file and put it into hdfs using :

```
hadoop fs -put /head.txt /head.txt
```

3) I have copy-paste your python code in mapper.py file and after saving copied it to hdfs :

```
hadoop fs -put /mapper.py /mapper.py
```

4) Finally I executed the below hadoop streaming command :

```
 hadoop jar /opt/hadoop/lib/hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.jar -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 -file /mapper.py -mapper mapper.py -input /head.txt -output /out.txt
```

`/opt/hadoop/lib/` is my hadoop library path. You can add your path here.
If you have set `HADOOP_HOME` in `.bashrc` file then no need to mention `bin/hadoop`.

Otherwise you can write `bin/hadoop` for executing the job.

This will definitely work for you. I have got following output in `out.txt` file.

```
value1 | bar value2 | value3
```

Comment: Sorry for delay in responding.  This is not working for me, I regret.  You're right to put -D mapped.reduce.tasks=0 in there; thanks.  The -file bit isn't necessary if you've put mapper.py in hdfs.  But then, when I run this super-basic example as you illustrate, it is definitely *not* working.   Can you try leaving out the -file mapper.py bit, deleting target and seeing if it still works?   I need this *so* badly to work.  Thx.

Comment: which version of hadoop and python are you using?

Comment: Amazon Elastic MapReduce, which is Hadoop 1.0.3 (or so it says); Python 2.6.6 (installed on all slaves + master).  Neither is as new as I would like, but 1.0.3 is the "most stable" option on Amazon.  I could build a new cluster if need be -- I'm desperate as I literally have billions of rows to clean....  Thanks much!!

Comment: @Todd: I would like to know why you have mentioned path of input and output like `hdfs:///rawdata/0208head.txt` in which there are 3 (`/`) after `hdfs:`. I believe it has to be 2 forward slash(/).

Comment: needs to be three, but have tried simply moving files to /user/hadoop where zero forward slashes are needed, and then changing streaming job to reflect.  No dice.